# SAS RobustReg Procedure output parameter estimates

Tags: sas, regression

I am using the robustreg procedure to perform a mutliple regression and it is not outputting the parameter estimates that I want. Here is an exmaple of the code I am using:

```
proc robustreg data=dataset4 outest=params fwls method=lts;
    model Y = V1 V2 / diagnostics leverage;
    output out=estimates predicted=Calculated;
run;
```

The data in the "params" dataset contains the "LTS Parameter Estimates" from the ouput but I would like it to contain the "Parameter Estimates for Final Weighted Least Squares Fit" estimates. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding `ods trace on;` before you run it, and looking at the log to see what ods tables are output?

Comment: Table names are listed in the documentation: https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/67523/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_rreg_details42.htm

Comment: Thank you both! I am not very familiar with using ODS so I didn't know these tables were available. I did find one that had the information I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds good.  I'll close this as a dup of the linked question once it has an upvoted answer and/or I can accept it (in 2 days).